# Images inside flex don't resize

Tags: css, image, resize, flexbox

I'm really without clue. I have done this div with flex attributes, it works fine, but if I resize the screen, images and text don't resize accordingly and everything goes on the next row and everything is kept same size.

```css
#qualities {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; 
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  flex-direction: row;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;

  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  box-align: center;  
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#eef199;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#qualities img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#qualities p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}

.cell {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #body #testata #container #beforehome #qualities video {
    height: auto;
  }

  .cell {height: 20%;}
  img {height: 10%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="qualities">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="http://www.md-health.com/images/1HT03553/Banana21.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="http://www.md-health.com/images/1HT03553/Banana21.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="http://www.md-health.com/images/1HT03553/Banana21.jpg"/>
  </div><br />
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Diverse qualità di mandorle sono usate per scopi differenti: le mandorle più comuni
      sono quelle dolci, usate spesso anche per condimento di piatti, poi ci sono le mandorle
      amare, usate spesso per l'olio di mandorla e infine le armelline, che sono le mandorle 
      contenute all'interno dei frutti come pesca o albicocca, le quali vengono trattate e
      una volta sgusciate sono come mandorle.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want things to be centered in the div and resize when the window is resized.

Comment: You have a media query but the css inside of it does absolutely nothing since you're calling them on classes that don't exist.  I think you mean to call them on IDs.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's right! Corrected, however, the problem still exists.

Comment: Apparently, by making the padding and margin 1px and adding in media .cell {height:5%} everything seems to work... but it's a sloppy workaround and I'd like to see a solution less... sloppy.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what your expected behavior is based on your description.  Do you want the pictures to always be on one line side by side?  And do you want the text to just get smaller?